# Calculate the distance $d$ from $\vec{y}$ to the straight line through $\vec{u}$ and the origin

Tags: linear-algebra, orthonormal

**Background**

Let $$\vec{y}= \left[ {\begin{array}{cc} 
                    5 \\                                     
                    1 \\                                     
                   10 \\                                     
                   \end{array} } \right]$$

and $$\vec{u}=\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   -7 \\
   3 \\
   -3 \\
  \end{array} } \right]$$

Calculate the distance $d$ from $\vec{y}$ to the line through $\vec{u}$ and the origin.

**My work so far**

Using the formula

$$d=\left|\vec{y}-\frac{\vec{y}\cdot\vec{u}}{|\vec{u}|}{\vec{u}}\right|$$

and plugging in

$$d=\left|\begin{pmatrix}5\\1\\10\end{pmatrix}-\frac{-62}{67}\begin{pmatrix}-7\\3\\-3\end{pmatrix}\right|$$

and then calculating

$$\frac{11\sqrt{38}}{\sqrt{67}}=8.284133.$$

Am I on the right track here? Or, where did I go wrong?

Comment: It should be $$d=\vert{\vec y-\frac{\vec y. \vec u}{|\vec u|}\hat u}\vert$$ Notice the unit vector $\hat u$.

Comment: Thanks SarGe. Would the unit vector $\hat u$ differ from that I have here?$d=\left|\begin{pmatrix}5\\1\\10\end{pmatrix}-\frac{-62}{67}\begin{pmatrix}-7\\3\\-3\end{pmatrix}\right|$

Comment: No! It is correct.

Comment: So, at this point, would the following be correct? $3\sqrt{14}-\frac{-62}{67}\sqrt{67}=18.79947...$ Just wanted to confirm that I'm computing this correctly.

Comment: Yes. That's correct.